# Galois of splitting field of $x^{12}-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Find the splitting field of $x^{12}-1$

We can write the roots as $$x = e^{in\frac{2\pi}{12}}, x = 1,\cdots, 12$$

Since all the roots can be achivied through self multiplication of $e^{i\frac{2\pi}{12}}$, the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\frac{2\pi}{12}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}/2 + i/2):\mathbb{Q}$. How to take $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\frac{2\pi}{12}}):\mathbb{Q}]$?

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}/2 + i/2):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + i):\mathbb{Q}]$$

I thought about finding the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i)$  is basically $\mathbb{Q}$ adjoined with every multiple of $\sqrt{3}+i$ plus every multiple of its inverse, that is, multiples of $\sqrt{3}-i$. We're at least talking about the set

$$\{a + b(\sqrt{3}+i) + c(\sqrt{3}-i)\}$$

BUT I think that

$$\{a + b(\sqrt{3}+i)\}$$

is already enough because we can get $\sqrt{3}-i$ from this set. So I think the splitting field should have degree $2$. Am I right? In this case, the Galois of this splitting field would be made by the identity automorphism and conjugate automorphism.

Comment: $\{ a + b (\sqrt{3} + i) : a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is not closed under multiplication; for example, $(\sqrt{3} + i)^2 = 2 + 2i \sqrt{3}$, and $(\sqrt{3} + i)^3 = 8i$.  Actually, it turns out $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + i) = \{ a + b \sqrt{3} + c i + d i \sqrt{3} : a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler makes sense, but how exactly do I arrive at this set?

Comment: Well, in this particular case, $(\sqrt{3} + i)^3 = 8i$ implies $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + i)$, and then you easily also get that $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + i)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the roots as $\zeta^k$ where $0 \le k < 12$.

Then, let $r$ be an automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ that takes $\zeta$ to $\zeta^a$. We know that $r(\zeta^k) = r(\zeta)^k = \zeta^{ak}$.

Therefore, automorphisms of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)/\Bbb Q$ are automorphisms of $\Bbb Z_{12}$, which is $(\Bbb Z_{12})^* \cong V_4$.

The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\Phi_{12} = x^4-x^2+1$ ([cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)).

---

$x^{12}-1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$

Comment: Why from $\zeta$ to $\zeta^8$?  Isn't there an easier way to do it? Is it much to ask what's wrong with my argument? Thanks :)

Comment: @Paprika It's an $s$ not an $8$. I've changed it to $a$.

Comment: Well you need one more argument to show it is all of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^\times$ (ie. $x^4-x^2+1= \prod_{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}^\times} (x-\zeta_a)$ is irreducible)

Comment: I think it's along step to talk about the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. We didn't see this specifically yet :c

Comment: @reuns cyclotomic polynomial basically guarantees irreducibility

Comment: Here we can say if it is not irreducible then the extension is of degree $ 2$, but  $(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^a) \not \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$  ($a = 11$ or $5$)